# How Do I find the Hash Value for a transaction?

Tags: hash, wallet-transfer, gdax

Long story short, tried to send ETH over to Huobi from GDAX. Did this last week with no problems. Transaction did not go through this time around. I was pissed. Went back and looked at Huobi deposit page and they now have a notice when you try to deposit ETH that if it comes from a Coinbase account it won't be credited. WTH?

Emailed Huobi. They asked me to provide my hash value and quantity. I assume they mean quantity of ETH when they asked for quantity. But how do I find my hash value (and what is a hash value) on the transfer? All I get from GDAX is their internal number identifying the transfer.

Help.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the history of the address Huobi gave you for deposit on Etherscan. If it doesn't show up there, check with Coinbase/GDAX staff.